# Isosceles Trapezoid question

Tags: geometry

I need help with this, any idea would be great. I tried for 2 days to solve this and still nothing, it looks like I need more informations to be able to solve this. Or maybe I'm just not good enough to solve this.[image]

Comment: Hint: show that $\Delta MBC$  is equilateral

Comment: $AD = CM = BC$. $\angle ABC = 60^0$ in $\triangle MBC$. So you can easily show $\triangle MBC$ is equilateral as Albus Dumbledore said.

Comment: Why AD = CM  ? How I prove that?

Comment: Is $AD \parallel CM$ or not?

Comment: You are right - the info given here is certainly not enough. The same trapezoid can be stretched horizontally to give another trapezoid with the same given properties.

Comment: Diagram shows them parallel but does not state it in question. Without that, you do not have a unique solution.

Comment: No, they don't give me AD || CM . So the info is certainly not enough. thank you !